# What python data structure can easily add new variables on the fly?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to iteratively capture data on a fixed list of items but the data fields/attributes are not fixed at the start.  As I iterate over each item new attributes may crop up which need to be added to the database.  What is a good way to do this?

For an easy example, suppose the list has three items (people) and these are their attributes:

- Person 1:  Height=168cm, Eyes=Brown
- Person 2:  Height=155cm, Occupation=Teacher
- Person 3:  Age=43, Country=Spain, Occupation=Writer

For Person 1 two variables need to be captured: height and eye color.  On the next iteration for Person 2 there is one existing attribute (height) and one new attribute (occupation).  Person 3 has three new attributes that need to be added.

The list of items is currently stored in a pandas dataframe.  My only idea so far is to create one field which stores all the attributes in a single dictionary item for each person (e.g.

```
[
    {"Height": "168cm", "Eyes": "Brown"},
    {"Height": "155cm, "Occupation": "Teacher"},
    {"Age": "43", "Country": "Spain", "Occupation": "Writer"}
]
```

Is there a better way to store the data which will be easier to query later on?  I'm very new to python.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a multi-dimensional dictionary. These are formatted as

```
dict2d = {
"Person1":{"Height": "168cm", "Eyes": "Brown"}
"Person2":{"Height": "155cm", "Occupation": "Teacher"}
"Person3":{"Age": "43", "Country": "Spain", "Occupation": "Writer"}
}
```

so in your code when you encounter a new element you can run something along the lines of

```
# code following the encounter
if person_name in dict2d:
  dict2d[person_name[new_data_name]] = new_data_value
else:
  dict2d[person_name] = {new_data_name : new_data_value}
# this is general pseudocode, there may be a few syntax errors
```

using these, you will be able to access an element of each person.